# Where is the proper place to assign variables in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, state-variable

```
uint x = 6;
uint y;

constructor(uint _y) {
  y = _y;
}
```

If the value of x is known beforehand, is it better to assign its value when it is declared or use the constructor (as with y)?

The docs suggest there is no preferred way:

> Before the constructor code is executed, state variables are initialised to their specified value if you initialise them inline, or their default value if you do not.

I mostly see inline initialization used for constants, while regular state variables have their value set in the constructor.  Is this just convention or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a universally preferred way and it probably boils down to personal preference. Here is my personal take on it:

- If the contract is a template that may be deployed multiple times
  with different values, then all the potentially changing values will
  be assigned in the constructor.
- On the other hand, if a contract is deployed only once and will never be reused (for sure), or
  if the value is a constant that will never change (ie. the address of
  a specific token that's already deployed), then I will assign it
  where it is declared and not in the constructor.

**TL;DR - In the constructor when you need flexibility, at the declaration when no flexibility is needed (ie. constants and unique contracts).**